# RefreshToken is null on ItemAdded, works fine on ItemUpdated

Tags: event-receivers, sharepoint-addin

I have an EventReceiver that is subscribed to both the ItemAdded and ItemUpdated event on a SharePoint list. I'm using the TokenHelper provided in the sample files, and have also tried the version [hosted on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/AppForSharePointWebToolkit/).

In both cases the properties object has all of the IDs and details required to access the list. The ItemUpdated event works fine through the code and gets to the end of the method but the ItemAdded event fails to retrieve a ClientContext (using `TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties)`) and on further investigation it appears that the `SharePointContextToken` that the `ReadAndValidateContextToken` method is generating does not have a refreshToken on it.

Digging a little deeper into the code, it would appear that my JsonWebToken is missing this claim. It only has the following claims: isbrowserhostedapp, appctx (times 2) and appctxsender (times three).

I can't work out why this is so any help on how to diagnose this would be appreciated.

Comment: This does not address your question, but, I have to ask - why use the client object model from within an Event Receiver rather than the server object model?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your question @Chloraphil as I'm still getting the hang of the terminology. I'm using SharePoint 2013 where the app is running external to SharePoint. Because of this I'm accessing it over an object model found in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll. The TokenHelper method that I'm using is designed to be used within RemoteEventReceivers.

Comment: OK. I read up a little bit on that stuff and I am not at all familiar with RemoteEventReceivers. Good luck.

Comment: @Matthew Steeples: Did you ever resolve this?  I am seeing the same thing.

Comment: @ChiliYago I'm afraid that as our app is internal only we skipped using the authentication provided to us by the request and instead authenticate with credentials that we already have from elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me is due to **app-only** authentication.

I am experiencing it with both the ItemAdded and the ItemUpdated remote event after a new item was created programmatically by the remote app (using AppOnlyAccessTokenForSPHost as opposed to UserAccessTokenForSPHost).

If the remote side created the item (can be seen when viewing the item in the SharePoint in the Created By info), then the context token received in the subsequent event does NOT contain a refresh token. This seems to be some kind of bug in the SharePoint (Online).

Answer (score 0):

The bug from Sharepoint still remains. I've wasted a lot of time before find this post. ContextToken received in ItemAdded doesn't contains RefreshToken that the TokenHelper needs in order to create a ClientContext.
After found this post i've tried with ItemUpdating and ItemAdding and my code works!